# Bitcoin full node running on Synology not visible to network

Tags: bitcoind

Last week I bought a Synology (918+) and starting running a Bitcoin full node (https://hub.docker.com/r/kylemanna/bitcoind).

To check whether the Bitcoin node can be found by the network, I checked on bitnodes.io with my external ip. Unfortunately my Bitcoin node is not reachable. I have forwarded ports 8333 - 8334 on my router. Checking whether port is open on canyouseeme.org, it gives as reason 'Connection refused'.

Another thing which confuses me is the following: if I check the logs, it gives the following (snapshot):

```
2020-05-14T11:01:13Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000009b091d2696ccfceae650b7f7a4fd8a9fd1893598647b9a886b4 height=1744386 version=0x20000000 log2_work=72.438235 tx=56041013 date='2020-05-14T11:00:46Z' progress=1.000000 cache=3.7MiB(28196txo) warning='22 of last 100 blocks have unexpected version'                                                    
2020-05-14T11:03:14Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000006d99735a74bae0c3bba509d56af9f8a01595099533c9bc34e6c height=1744387 version=0x20000000 log2_work=72.438236 tx=56041054 date='2020-05-14T11:03:13Z' progress=1.000000 cache=3.7MiB(28220txo) warning='22 of last 100 blocks have unexpected version'
```

What my understanding is that `height` is the block height. How can this be `height=1744387` when we're currently around block height 630335? What am I missing here?

Please note that I am both new to running a NAS and a Bitcoin full node, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you connected to the testnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the block count of testnet: https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/. The Docker script automatically generates a bitcoin.conf configuration and launches bitcoind. Somehow `testnet=1` got set in `bitcoin.conf` or bitcoind was run with -testnet at the command line.

Comment: Yes, this was indeed the problem, thanks for clarifying! Now downloading the main chain. Going very slow (for days now already), but enough threads on here how to speed that up. :-)

Comment: For reference, downloading the entire blockchain on my Raspberry Pi over a 80/5mbps cable internet connection took a couple MONTHS. Too many nodes these days are bandwidth limited or pruning, significantly slowing a full download. My point? It takes patience to download it the first time.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know. So I guess downloading should take a couple of weeks. Probably the 4 GB memory being the bottleneck. Anyway, thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: When bootstrapping my node CPU rarely wen above 25% and memory rarely above 75% on my 1.2ghz RPi 3B with 1Gig RAM. Unless I'm missing something, it appears the bottleneck is a lack of other nodes that have the full blockchain and allow you enough bandwidth to download. Just my $.02. Regardless, a long wait is likely